# how to only transform.position the x position and not also the y c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help with changing one of my c# scripts. I have created 2d sprite buttons in unity that have a box collider on and use the OnMouseDown() function. I have a c# script to make the buttons follow the player and to offset them so that they aren't on top of the player. But when my player jumps, the y and x position of the buttons change as well, so the buttons 'jump' aswell. I need to keep the coords.y = playerTransform.position.y; and offset because the button needs to be offset. I would like for the position of the buttons to change on the x axis but not the y.

Here is my code:

```
Vector3 coords = transform.position; //stores the current camera position in coords

coords.x = playerTransform.position.x; // set coords to be equal to the current players x coordinate
coords.y = playerTransform.position.y;
coords.x += offsetX;
coords.y += offsetY;
transform.position = coords; //set the cameras position to be equal to coords
```

Comment: Leave out the lines that change the `y` ... ?

Comment: i agree with derHugo. change the coord.y to equal some constant number.  or delete or lerp to give it a slight bounce with the player.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform.Translate(new Vector3(playerTransform.x + offsetX, 0, 0));
```

This takes less code and adds the Vector3 that you pass in to transform.position. Just set the coordinates that you don't want to change to 0.